# RPM specfile for C/C++ project: how do I know how to fill in Requires and BuildRequires fields?

Tags: rhel, package-management, rpm, make, libraries

I have several C/C++ projects with sources and makefiles and I'm trying to pack them into rpms. Defining the dependencies for the created packages has become a problem for me. Concretely I need to find out what to put into the **Requires** and **BuildRequires** fields of the specfile.

1. Assuming that **Requires** field requests the list of libraries used by the executable during the runtime, I am trying to parse `ldd`'s output and pass it to the `rpm -q --whatrequires` ([here is my simple script](http://pastebin.com/aQNiWR6j)). Moreover, I need to do that recursively (get dependencies for the packages that contain first-level dependencies) someway.
2. I can guess that **BuildRequires** field should contain all the *-devel.rpm packages with a С/С++ headers (***only?***). I can check several source files manually, but I don't understand how to analyze the thousands lines of code...

Parsing sources by #include keyword can lead to collision (because of headers with the same name but lying in different directories). Is it possible to force Make script or gcc to be more verbose in order to define which headers had been used by default? This would solve the second problem.

Lack of such a useful tool for the developers in RHEL-based distros seems strange for me.

Comment: That would entirely depend on which libraries your projects use. You should know it from your sources and `ldd` output. I don't see any usefulness in such kind of tool anyway.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that you have faced with a situation when  you had inherited a project with a lots of *.hpp/*.h or *.cpp/*.c with a hundreds of included headers overall and now you need to maintain the code and build the packages. Please tell how would deal with that?

Comment: If you have a lot of files in your project then I'm pretty certain you should have a build system (autotools, cmake, scons etc). You should get all the information from a Makefile or from build system files.

Comment: I do have a Makefile (rather a lots of Makefiles), but unfortunately I can't see one-to-one correspondence between LD parameters and packages...

Comment: Which build system do you use?

Answer (score 3):

The Fedora RPM tools are quite smart in figuring out the runtime dependencies on their own, unless they can't be deduced from the installable files themselves. The dependencies for building you'll figure out by yourself. Perhaps [Fedora's RPM guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/) is of help (I'm a Fedora user, and this is the best resource I know; maybe your distribution has more relevant documentation for your use). Fedora offers `mock(1)`, which creates a clean environment with just the built tools mentioned to build the package. It is a real pain (*very* slow, as it essentially creates a full system in a chroot by downloading everything for each build), but a useful final check.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I get information in order to provide explicit dependencies for the spec file:

- **Requires**: see my script [here](http://vitalyisaev2.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-find-out-which-of-installed-rpm.html);
- **BuildRequires**: use [auti-buildrequires](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/auto-buildrequires/) tool from Richard Jones;